# How to code for game controller joysticks?

Tags: android, joystick

I am attempting to write an application which takes input from the Wikipad's dual thumb joysticks. I have been unable to find sample code that does this or developer documentation for the Wikipad. The NVIDIA Shield is a similar device that I would also like to support, and they [have a page on this](http://docs.nvidia.com/tegra/data/How_To_Support_Android_Game_Controllers.html), but the useful links are broken.

Can anyone point me to some sample code that shows you to develop Android java code for a game controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Wikipad and they gave me access to this document which appears not to be available elsewhere:

http://support.wikipad.com/attachments/token/rzkcbft13bam5l6/?name=WikipadController-DeveloperReference.pdf

I also found this very useful:

https://devs.ouya.tv/developers/docs/controllers

Basically the answer is that you override the onGenericMotionEvent callback of a view or activity.